# Calculated Member in Excel Disappearing Depending on Column Order

Tags: excel, pivot-table, mdx, member

I am trying create a calculated member in Excel for my tabular model. I do not have access to the model in SQL and cannot change the code there.

My goal is to create a calculated member that contains all branches except Atlanta. Here is the mdx code I have in Excel.

```
aggregate([Branch].[Branch].[Branch].MEMBERS)-[Branch].[Branch].&[101 - ATLANTA]
```

The code works well, as can be seen in the following pivot table.

[Working ptable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7lsR1.png)

Working MDX code:

```
WITH
MEMBER [Branch].[Branch].[All].[ExclAtl] as aggregate([Branch].[Branch].
    [Branch].MEMBERS)-[Branch].[Branch].&[101 - ATLANTA]
SELECT NON EMPTY Hierarchize(DrilldownMember(CrossJoin({[Branch].[Branch].
    [All],[Branch].[Branch].[Branch].AllMembers}, {([Currency Type].
    [Currency Type].[All])}), [Branch].[Branch].[Branch].AllMembers, 
    [Currency Type].[Currency Type])) 
DIMENSION PROPERTIES PARENT_UNIQUE_NAME,HIERARCHY_UNIQUE_NAME ON COLUMNS  
FROM (SELECT ({[Branch].[Branch].[All].[caseTest], [Branch].[Branch].[All].
    [ExclAtl], [Branch].[Branch].&[101 - ATLANTA]},{[Currency Type].
    [Currency Type].&[Base (USD)]}) ON COLUMNS  FROM [Model]) 
WHERE ([Scale].[Currency Scale].[All],[Reserve Class].[Reserve Class Line].
    [All],[Param1].[Gross Ceded Net].&[Gross],[Measures].[Total Incurred]) 
CELL PROPERTIES VALUE, FORMAT_STRING, LANGUAGE, BACK_COLOR, FORE_COLOR, 
    FONT_FLAGS
```

The problem is the ExclAtl calculated member does not show up when I switch the Currency Type and Branch columns. Why is this? Is there a better way to type the MDX code in Excel so the ExclAtl member will show for any column order I choose?

[Not working ptable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uLKCm.png)

MDX Code (ExclAtl not showing)

```
WITH
MEMBER [Branch].[Branch].[All].[ExclAtl] as aggregate([Branch].[Branch].
    [Branch].MEMBERS)-[Branch].[Branch].&[101 - ATLANTA]
SELECT NON EMPTY Hierarchize(DrilldownMember(CrossJoin({[Currency Type].
    [Currency Type].[All],[Currency Type].[Currency Type].[Currency 
    Type].AllMembers}, {([Branch].[Branch].[All])}), [Currency Type].
    [Currency Type].[Currency Type].AllMembers, [Branch].[Branch])) 
DIMENSION PROPERTIES PARENT_UNIQUE_NAME,HIERARCHY_UNIQUE_NAME ON COLUMNS  
FROM (SELECT ({[Currency Type].[Currency Type].&[Base (USD)]},{[Branch].
    [Branch].[All].[caseTest], [Branch].[Branch].[All].[ExclAtl], [Branch].
    [Branch].&[101 - ATLANTA]}) ON COLUMNS  FROM [Model]) 
WHERE ([Scale].[Currency Scale].[All],[Reserve Class].[Reserve Class Line].
    [All],[Param1].[Gross Ceded Net].&[Gross],[Measures].[Total Incurred]) 
CELL PROPERTIES VALUE, FORMAT_STRING, LANGUAGE, BACK_COLOR, FORE_COLOR, 
    FONT_FLAGS
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies here:

```
{([Branch].[Branch].[All])}
```

It won't return the [Branch].[Branch].[All].[ExclAtl] member.
You should use instead:

```
{([Branch].[Branch].AllMembers)}
```

Comment: Thank you! Is there a way to make this edit in Excel? Or is there a setting I can change? I don't have access to the tabular model to edit the mdx code in SQL. I am doing everything in Excel.

Comment: You can play with removing totals. I expect that may help, because of simplifying of the generated code (no DrilldownMember, etc). But the best way is to add a separate attribute.